# How to initialize bit.dev workspace with JavaScript

Tags: bit.dev

I want to create and publish components using bit.dev with JavaScript. But when initialize a new workspace using bit new react (react is the template), the react template is generated with typescript. I want to use javascript instead. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the default react-env and the templates provided, but you can also create your own environment without Typescript and your own templates. I think that you can get by with the starting templates at the beginning without hussle, and then once you understand better environments and templating, create some of your own.

### Steps to create a JS component from a template

##### Create an environment

```
bit new react example_workspace
cd example_workspace
```

now you can explore the available templates:

```
bit templates
```

The output will be:

```
{...}
teambit.react/react
    react (a basic react component)
    react-context (a react context component)
    react-hook (a react hook component)
    react-js (a basic react component in js)
    react-env (customize the base React env with your configs and tools)

teambit.harmony/aspect
    aspect (extend Bit capabilities)

{...}
```

##### Create the JS component

So, now, we can use the react-js template:

```
bit create react-js my_component
```

The output will be:

```
1 component(s) were created

my-org.my-scope/my_component
    location: my-scope/my_component
    env:      teambit.react/react (set by template)
    package:  @my-org/my-scope.my_component


env configuration is according to workspace variants, template config or --env flag. learn more at https://bit.dev/docs/envs/using-envs
```

Source: [CLI Reference](https://bit.dev/reference/reference/cli-reference/#templates)